# Reflected DOM XSS Portswigger Lab

Tags: web-application, xss, burp-suite, reflected-xss, dom

I'm a total beginner and im trying to solve Portswigger Academy labs. I'm studying on XSS right now and im stuck in somewhere.

> Lab Details:This lab demonstrates a reflected DOM vulnerability. Reflected DOM vulnerabilities occur when the server-side application processes data from a request and echoes the data in the response. A script on the page then processes the reflected data in an unsafe way, ultimately writing it to a dangerous sink.**
> To solve this lab, create an injection that calls the alert() function.//

So, there is a JSON file on the lab and it escapes quotation marks.
There is something like this in response:

`{"results":[],"searchTerm":"test"}`

and to espace this I've done this:

`GET /search-results?search=\"alert(1)}//`

and response turns to this:

`"results":[],"searchTerm":"\\" alert(1)}//"}`

and everything is ok. I escaped the quotation marks. I've thought that if I enter the `\"alert(1)}//` term on searchbox i can solve the lab, but it doesnt work. The only way to solve this lab is
`\"+alert(1)}// or \"-alert(1)}//`

But why do we need this `+` and `-` symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are in the context of a string inside a JavaScript object. So you need to keep the string in a correct format for the payload to execute. By including the + or - you make sure the string does not break.

Plus is a proper way to concatenate strings. Concatenating a string with a void function results in the string "undefined" being added to the original and is therefor a valid statement.

Dash or minus does a subtraction from the string, which in JavaScript results in NaN and is therefore allowed too.